# C# ввод числа в консоль

Tags: c#, консоль

Как ввести три числа с клавиатуры в консоль через пробел в языке программирования C#?

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] splitLine = line.Split(' ');

    foreach (var sLine in splitLine)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sLine);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Объясните подробнее, пожалуйста, решение пошагово. Не совсем понял foreach

Comment: @Redl, вы вводите числа через пробел в консольку и нажимаете Enter. Получили строку и выполняете Split по пробелу, в итоге получаете массив из цифр, затем foreach выводит их на экран.

Comment: `foreach` - это вид цикла, он берет  элемент `sline` из набора `splitLine`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно воспользоваться `string str=Console.ReadLine();`
После этой инструкции будет ожидаться ввод пользователя в консоль и по нажатию Enter данные будут присвоены переменной str.

Надо помнить, что ReadLine() возвращает данные в строковом представлении и поэтому, если вам нужны цифры для каких-то арефметических операций, то вы должны сделать явное преобразование. Например, если вы хотите преобразовать в целое число, то можете вызвать    `Int32.TryParse` . Для других числовых типов есть аналогичные функции преобразования.

Для того, что бы считать несколько цифр, вы должны либо вводить цифры через какой-то разделитель, а потом выполнять `Split` или в цикле вызывать `string str=Console.ReadLine();` N-ое кол-во раз.

Comment: А ка использовать Split, если введена строка, и нужно отдельный переменным присвоить отдельные числа разделенные через пробел в введенной строке?

Comment: @Redl, В строке есть делитель?

Comment: ,да, вводится три числа через пробел

Comment: @Redl, внизу tCode дал пример. Он верный, только учтите, что если вам потребуются арефметические операции, то нужно преобразовать строку в число явно.

Comment: а как теперь каждое число, которое мы получили в массиве, перевести из строки в число?

Comment: @Redl, добавил.